# Two variable function convex test

Tags: calculus

For which $a,b,c\in \mathbb{R}$ is function 
$$f(x,y)=ax^2+bxy+cy^2$$
convex in $\mathbb{R}^2$? Any ideas on how to approach this problem?

Comment: Check for which values of $(a,b,c)$ the Hessian matrix of $f$ is positive semi-definite.

Comment: ... so, by Sylvester's criterion, as soon as $a\geq 0$ and $4ac-b^2\geq 0$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\nabla f =\begin{bmatrix} 2ax+by \\ bx+2cy \end{bmatrix} $$

$$\nabla^2f=\begin{bmatrix} 2a & b \\ b & 2c\end{bmatrix}$$

$\nabla^2f$ is positive semidefinite when $2a>0$ and if its determinant is positive.

$a\geq0$ and $(2a)(2c)-b^2=4ac-b^2 \geq 0$.